# Convert a string describing a working shift into a integer that equals the hours

Tags: php, time

**Problem**

In my php webapp a user can create a new event with the following properties:

- StartDate (DATE)
- EndDate (DATE)
- OpeningHours (STRING)

I want to use these properties to calculate the number of hours the event is going as an DOUBLE. (because these hours define how long the working shift is). Basically start and end date is given in a normalized way, but the opening hours can be given in any kind of way.

**Example**

So if a user enters the following data

- StartDate: "2015-07-02"
- EndDate: "2015-07-05"
- OpeningHours: first day from 9 am to 6:30pm, other days till 6pm

I want to calculate that the total number of events hours is 36,5 hours (first day 9 hours + other three days 9,5 hours each).

**Constraints**

There are almost endless ways to describe opening hours, here are just a few:

- "from 9 am to 6 pm, except last day till 6:30 pm"
- "from 9 am to 6 pm, except saturday from 9 am am to 6:30 pm"
- "first day from 9 am to 6 pm, second day from 9 am to 6 pm, third day from 9 am to 6:30 pm"
- "July 2nd from 9 am to 6:30pm, other days till 6 pm"

I don't expect to be able catch all phrases, but at least the mayority.

**My Approachso far**

My basic approach so far is the following:

1. Calculate the number of days the event is going (e.g. 4 days)
2. Parse the OpeningHours String and get all substrings that describe one or more shifts (e.g. "from 9 am to 6 pm, except last day till 6:30 pm" becomes "9 am to 6pm" and "except last day till 6:30pm")
3. For each substring calculate how long the shift is, that it describes (e.g. "9 am to 6pm" is 9 hours and "except last day till 6:30pm" is 9.5 hours)
4. For each substring describing a shift duration try to guess, to how many days it should be applied to (e.g. 9.5 hour shift only to one day, the 9 hour shift to all other)
5. Add up all numbers to calculate (36.5 hours total)

Step 3 is hard because sometimes on substring describing a shift has not the complete information, but instead references a another substring (e.g. "except last day till 6:30pm" implies that it also starts at 9 am).
Step 4 is hard because there are many different indicators that can define onto how many days a described shift should be applied to (e.g. "except last day..." implies that this shift is only applied to one day).

Has anybody run into similiar problem and might be able to guide me through a solution, that would at least catch the majority of phrases and calculate the hours properly?
Or maybe there does even already exist a library or best practise approach that solves this problem in an elegant way

Comment: I would have 2 tables: `event` and `event_time`. Where 2nd table would have `from_datetime` and `to_datetime` `DATETIME` fields. Then you can easily calculate the duration by day/week/event/etc. With this case, you can even have multiple records on single day, for example `from 9am to 11am and from 4pm to 9pm`.